# All features disabled (touchpad and head gesture)

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I just create a simple app to my glass device.

However sometime while in using the device, i heard a sound (like a beep) and the screen turn off. The device don´t answer to any of my wakeup command. I tap the touchpad and move my head and nothing happen.

So i need to press the power button (it makes a little sound) and then press it again.
Now my glass come back to live.

I´m guessing that my app what's making it happen.
What could I be doing wrong?
My app just start and read a QRCODE using the Zxing.

```
12-19 16:33:09.109: D/dalvikvm(378): GC_CONCURRENT freed 381K, 7% free 9732K/10375K, 

paused 5ms+10ms
12-19 16:33:09.296: I/DonManager(197): onTimerExpired!
12-19 16:33:09.296: V/EyeGestureService(197): Native call nativeIsEyeGestureDetectorRunning
12-19 16:33:09.296: I/DonManager(197): Timer expired and sensors action, so switching to state = DEFER_TO_SENSORS
12-19 16:33:09.296: V/DonManager(197): Switching from state: TIMED_FORCED_DONNED --> DEFER_TO_SENSORS
12-19 16:33:09.296: I/DonManager(197): Stopping the FORCED_DONNED timer.
12-19 16:33:09.296: V/DonManager(197): DonDoffManager: deferring to sensors.  State = DOFFED
12-19 16:33:09.296: I/DonManager(197): Calling onStateChanged(): DOFFED
12-19 16:33:09.296: V/InputHub(197): Cancelling all event sequences.
12-19 16:33:09.296: D/TouchpadManager(197): Requesting touchpad sleep mode = true
12-19 16:33:09.296: I/GlassSystemServer(197): Applying device state: doffed.
12-19 16:33:09.335: W/DonStateReceiver(456): Received com.google.glass.action.DON_STATE even though we are not registered.
12-19 16:33:09.351: V/EyeGestureService(197): Native call nativeIsEyeGestureDetectorRunning
12-19 16:33:09.351: I/GlassSystemServer(197): Broadcast of DonState doffed ending, executing onDone sequence.
12-19 16:33:09.367: V/HeadGestureManager(197): Removing listener: com.google.android.glass.server.SystemServerHub$2@417436b0 for head gesture: GLOBAL_LOOK_UP
12-19 16:33:09.367: V/HeadGestureManager(197): Removed listener: com.google.android.glass.server.SystemServerHub$2@417436b0 from gesture: GLOBAL_LOOK_UP
12-19 16:33:09.367: V/HeadGestureManager(197): Last listener for gesture: GLOBAL_LOOK_UP was removed.  Unregistering with service.
12-19 16:33:09.367: V/HeadGestureService(197): Native call nativeIsGlobalLookUpDetectorRunning
12-19 16:33:09.367: V/HeadGestureService(197): Native call nativeIsGlobalLookUpGestureEnabled
12-19 16:33:09.367: V/HeadGestureService(197): Native call nativeIsGlobalLookUpGestureEnabled
12-19 16:33:09.367: V/HeadGestureService(197): Native call nativeEnableGlobalLookUpDetector
12-19 16:33:09.367: V/HeadGestureService(197): Removing a callback for gesture: GLOBAL_LOOK_UP
12-19 16:33:09.367: V/HeadGestureService(197): Invariant enforcement for gesture: GLOBAL_LOOK_UP found numCallbacks=0 and isRunning=true
12-19 16:33:09.367: V/HeadGestureService(197): Gesture: GLOBAL_LOOK_UP no longer requires a detector, so disconnecting the service listener...
12-19 16:33:09.367: V/HeadGestureService(197): Disconnecting the hardware listener for gesture: GLOBAL_LOOK_UP
12-19 16:33:09.367: V/HeadGestureService(197): Disabling the GLU detector ...
12-19 16:33:09.375: D/audio_hw_primary(109): select_output_device: output_type: 1, base_headset_volume: 1
12-19 16:33:09.382: I/Sensors(197): Calling abortWaitForLookupGesture
12-19 16:33:09.382: I/GlassGestureService::DMPManager(197): Calling MPLSensor::waitForLookupGesture()...
12-19 16:33:09.382: V/Sensors(197): Waiting for DMP gesture...
12-19 16:33:09.382: I/Sensors(197):  done calling abortWaitForLookupGesture
12-19 16:33:09.382: I/HeadGestureService(197): handleDmpGestureDetected called with 0 at timestamp 1479823178
12-19 16:33:09.382: I/HeadGestureService(197): Detected GLOBAL_LOOK_UP gesture.  Setting NUDGE inhibition timer.
12-19 16:33:09.382: V/HeadGestureService(197): GLOBAL_LOOK_UP service listener called but not enabled.
12-19 16:33:09.390: V/HeadGestureService(197): ...Success!
12-19 16:33:09.523: I/UserEventService(561): Logging user event: [action=DOFFED, data=|ohd_active=1|don_time_ms=30002|], performance stats: [GlassUserEventPerformanceStats <  battery_charge_when_full_uah: 503000  battery_state_of_charge_uah: 498000  battery_temperature_milli_centigrade: 30000  board_temperature_milli_centigrade: 40970  frequency_scaling_governor: 1  frequencyStat <    duration_ms: 8769750    frequency_hz: 300000  >  frequencyStat <    duration_ms: 437000    frequency_hz: 600000  >  frequencyStat <    duration_ms: 175890    frequency_hz: 800000  >  frequencyStat <    duration_ms: 28140    frequency_hz: 1008000  >  reported_soc: 99  total_bytes_sent: 0  total_kernel_ms: 9410780>]
12-19 16:33:14.625: I/AlarmManager(197): AlarmManager wakeup [pkg=android, intent=Intent { act=android.content.syncmanager.SYNC_ALARM flg=0x14 (has extras) }].
12-19 16:33:17.656: D/dalvikvm(378): GC_CONCURRENT freed 401K, 7% free 9738K/10375K, paused 6ms+7ms
12-19 16:33:17.953: W/CheckinRequestBuilder(336): Unknown phone type: 0 id=null
```

Comment: No, the battery is full....This log `I/DonManager(197): onTimerExpired!` maybe the reason. He force the touchpad to sleep state and disable the headgesturemanager. But I can't find any information about this DonManager.

Comment: Do you have head detection on? This can sometimes cause what you are seeing.

Comment: In my app or in system? In my app I don´t use it. I´m listing to the GestureDetector such as the this: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/touch

Comment: I have strong feeling that it can be caused by overheating. Because I don´t change any line of my code, I’m the problem don´t happen anymore. Yesterday when the problem is happening, I´m eventually receiving the message “Glass must cool down to run smoothly".